# UIView animation vs gif. Which one should I choose if I want to get better performance?

Tags: ios, gif, cabasicanimation

I have a `UITableView`. I am adding a loader on each of its cells with custom animation. It is just an image of a ball which keeps bouncing.
Will adding a gif lead to better performance, or is using `CABasicAnimation`, like I am currently doing, a better option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CABasicAnimation is a fine way of doing this. CA runs very close to the metal on iOS and you will get good performance out of it.

Practically speaking, performance considerations are probably not very important for this scenario, as the animation you describe shouldn't stress any modern iOS device. But if you've already got it implemented in CoreAnimation, I would definitely advise sticking with that.